# QML TreeView: How to checked/unchecked all child items

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I have a CheckBox for each item on TreeView, so when I checked/unchecked parent item, how to checked/unchecked its all child items?
This is my code:

```
TreeView {

    id: treeview
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    headerVisible: false
    model: TreeViewController

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Name"
        role: "name_role"
    }

    TableViewColumn {
        title: "Description"
        role: "description_role"
    }

    itemDelegate: listTreeDelegate

    Component {
        id: listTreeDelegate
        Item {
            id: listTreeDelegateItem

            CheckBox {
                id: checkbox
                checked:false
                visible: styleData.value === undefined ? false : true
                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    onClicked: {
                        if (parent.checked === true) {
                            parent.checked = false
                        } else {
                            parent.checked = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop through all children and uncheck each one.

Comment: @folibis I updated my code. Can you show how to implement loop in this? I'm a beginner in qml.